# Difference between 2 ways of assigning value by pandas ix method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm wondering why the former way of assignment (A) failed.

Can anyone explain this?

- (A): .ix and then sliced
- (B): .ix with sliced indexer

pandas version : 0.18.0

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"A":[10,11,12]})
indexer = [0,1,2]

# orginal DataFrame
print(a)
#     A
# 0  10
# 1  11
# 2  12

# (A) assignment failed
a.ix[indexer,"A"][0] = 999
print(a)
#     A
# 0  10
# 1  11
# 2  12

# (B) assignment succeeded
a.ix[indexer[0],"A"] = 999
print(a)
#      A
# 0  999
# 1   11
# 2   12
```

Thank you in advance.

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

Comment: See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) for a more detailed explanation